# component build not finding dependancies

Tags: json, node.js, git

I have following folder structure

```
root
- components
   - main
   - secondary
```

inside root I have a component.json defined as follows

```
{
  "name": "Application-Name",
  "repository": "application-name/app",
  "description": "Application-Name app root",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "dependencies": {
    "Application-Name/main": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

inside the main I also have a component.json with similar structure.

When I try to call component build I get the following error...

```
fatal : no remote found for dependency "application-name/main@0.0.1". 
Visit http://component.github.io/troubleshooting for help.
```

I have run component validate on both the component.json files and both return no errors. I have also been to http://component.github.io/troubleshooting as the error message suggested but have still found no joy. If I understand it correctly it is trying to find the component on git hub the default route when a component builds but I have no idea how to tell the build where the other component is.

Do i have to have a local git repository? what am I doing wrong.

I am very new to component, git and node if answering or needing more info from me please be gentle :)

Thanks so much!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running package.json dependencies when dependencies are not global](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885110/running-package-json-dependencies-when-dependencies-are-not-global)