# Running package.json dependencies when dependencies are not global

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, gulp, package.json

Let's say I have a package.json with "rimraf" as a dependency in it. "rimraf" is not installed globally. What command, from the command prompt, can I enter to run "rimraf"? Something like "npm run-command rimraf?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd run

```
./node_modules/.bin/rimraf
```

or if it is some common task, I'd add it to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ..."
}
```

and then call `npm run clean`. Commands in `scripts` automatically resolve with `./node_modules/.bin`.

Comment: I had no idea that npm automatically symlinked dependency bin scripts with `node_modules/.bin/`. That's awesome! Thanks :D

Comment: Yup! All the shell scripts that get installed globally when you do `-g` are put in `.bin` when you install locally.